# I get MDB_MAP_RESIZED error in Unity, how can I fix it?

Tags: unity-game-engine

Excuse me if this has been posted before, but I can't find a solution that works for me.

When I run a little 2D-game I'm working on in Unity I get following errors:

```
> Assertion failed on expression: 'm_ErrorCode == MDB_MAP_RESIZED || !HasAbortingErrors()
> Artifact meta info not present for hash 306bf9d63d75727c0b63ec8f203f76ac
> Asset database transaction committed twice!
> Assertion failed on expression: 'errors == MDB_SUCCESS || errors == MDB_NOTFOUND'
```

Despite that everything in the game seems to be running correctly, but the error keeps popping up.

Somebody suggested that it might have to do with the imported sprites, but all my sprites are PNG, which should be standard for Unity? Reimporting the sprites didn't seem to affect the error.

What could be causing the error? How can I identify it and fix it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check to make sure you have an active Licence in your Unity hub, if not sign up for one , they are free.

I've also just had this error -

saved and closed unity Editor
opened up hub checked for valid license
there was a hub update.- did that.
reopened Unity editor no more error.

May have just needed a restart after being open for 4 days - more likely the hub update wasn't telling the editor it was licenced properly.

Comment: This worked! My license was up to date, but there was an update for Unity Hub. I updated it and restarted my computer just to be sure. Tested many times, but the issue did not appear again. I should've thought of this before. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Had this issue early into my development, I just reset my unity after saving and checked for updates in my license.